# Getting Testnet Tokens

Tags: testnet

I am trying to get testnet tokens by running

```
solana airdrop 1 HYvnptcanM1x2jsPvLC8qjvYvxXWQUdm6ZRhk1YiUHe6 --url https://api.testnet.solana.com
```

And I get

```
Requesting airdrop of 1 SOL
Error: error sending request for url (https://api.testnet.solana.com/): connection closed before message completed
```

Is there a better way to get SOL Testnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`solana airdrop 1 ADDRESS --url testnet`

finally worked out after waiting a couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

there is a site to get faucets
[solfaucet](https://solfaucet.com/)
You can simply go there and paste your wallet address and then you can have them.
but sol airdrop limit is
1 for testnet
2 for devnet

Comment: I do not manage to get any on testnet, even if the UI sais it worked the Tx hash I get is not found

https://explorer.solana.com/tx/kQRZx13veJDsPBkh6wdwftq9g9Qmnrgz7tS7wPbyu5VtZoLLc1nNmfrAagungCznWuaQWtyoNqSPbE5yRC7V2Aw?cluster=testnet